# Routing Rx and Tx traffic to/from a port on separate interfaces

Tags: network-interface, routing

I have a Guest OS that looks sort of like this:

```
             Host OS          Guest OS
Intranet --- eth0 -------|--- eth0
           / eth1_in  <--|--< eth1 <--\
<some app> |                          | nc -N host_ip 4242
           \ eth2_out >--|--> eth2 >--/
```

Basically, I want the standard `netcat` app to send all its outgoing traffic through `eth1` and get all its incoming traffic from `eth2`. All the rest of the traffic uses the default `eth0` interface.

In the Guest OS

```
ip route host_ip/32 dev eth1
```

routes all the outgoing traffic, but how should I route the incoming traffic? Will `netcat` work oblivious of all this jiggery-pokery behind the scenes? Or is there a better approach.

PS: My actual situation is that the `host_ip` is actually another machine's IP address but the `<some app>` will do some magic to replay a previously-recorded `netcat` session, but that is a separate issue.